# Kubernetes - Vertical scaling increase cpu usage without terminating any instances

Tags: kubernetes

I'm following a guide where when the cpu usage is reached, the instances in the guide shows that the old pods gets deleted and new ones get created.

But in my case, it seems like the CPU is increasing without the need of recreating the pods. Is something changed in the latest versions?

```
kubectl top pod vpa-demo-deployment-59f444664f-7hwk5
NAME                                   CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
vpa-demo-deployment-59f444664f-7hwk5   201m         3Mi
```

cat 01-VPA-DemoApplication.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vpa-demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: vpa-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vpa-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vpa-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vpa-nginx
        image: stacksimplify/kubenginx:1.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "5m"
            memory: "5Mi"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vpa-demo-service-nginx
  labels:
    app: vpa-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: vpa-nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31232
```

cat 02-VPA-Manst.yml

```
apiVersion: "autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: kubengix-vpa
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind: Deployment
    name: vpa-demo-deployment
  resourcePolicy:
    containerPolicies:
      - containerName: '*'
        minAllowed:
          cpu: 5m
          memory: 5Mi
        maxAllowed:
          cpu: 1
          memory: 500Mi
        controlledResources: ["cpu", "memory"]
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the guide you're following ?

Comment: Its actually a video tutorial. What is the default behavior when vertical scaling is setup?

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation for this is **restart free ("in-place") update of pod requests**, which may be used as the preferred update mechanism by the `"Auto"` mode. You can read about it in the official **Vertical Pod Autoscaler** documentation in [this section](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/README.md#quick-start):

> - `"Auto"`: VPA assigns resource requests on pod creation as well as updates them on existing pods using the preferred update mechanism.
>   Currently this is equivalent to  `"Recreate"`  (see below). Once
>   restart free ("in-place") update of pod requests is available, it may
>   be used as the preferred update mechanism by the  `"Auto"`  mode.
>   **NOTE:**  This feature of VPA is experimental and may cause downtime for your applications.

It's also mentioned in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eic6kBa3QAc) KubeCon talk.